# Map polygons with holes in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

What I'm trying to achieve is situation like this: http://rbrundritt.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/image3.png
According this tutorial: http://guido1993.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/complex-polygons-in-bing-maps/
My complete code is:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace MapTest
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            MapPolygon shape = new MapPolygon();
            List<BasicGeoposition> positions = new List<BasicGeoposition>();

            positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 48, Longitude = 18 });
            positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 48, Longitude = 20 });
            positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 49, Longitude = 19 });
            positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 48, Longitude = 18 });

            positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 48.25, Longitude = 18.5 });
            positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 48.75, Longitude = 19 });
            positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 48.25, Longitude = 19.5 });

            positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 48.25, Longitude = 18.5 });
            positions.Add(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 48, Longitude = 18 });

            shape.Path = new Geopath(positions);
            ctrlMap.MapElements.Add(shape);
        }
    }
}
```

There is only map control in XAML file.
I tried to use the same coordinates within Windows Store App using Bing SDK and polygon was displayed correctly.
When I try to display Polyline with the same coordinates in Windows Phone, it is also displayed.
Isn’t it supported in Windows Phone 8.1?
Or should I use different classes?
Is it possible to have some response when polygon should be displayed that it is not valid (if it is so)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug and won't be fixed in Windows 10 as well. [Please vote on UserVoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/6609379-let-us-draw-polygons-with-holes-on-the-mapcontrol) if you need this feature as well.